# How to create and return a Zarr file from xarray Dataset?

Tags: python, file, geospatial, python-xarray, zarr

How would I go about creating and return a file `new_zarr.zarr` from a xarray Dataset?

I know `xarray.Dataset.to_zarr()` exists but this returns a `ZarrStore` and I must return a `bytes-like` object.

I have tried using the `tempfile` module but am unsure how to proceed, how would I write an xarray.Dataset to a `bytes-like object` that reurns a `.zarr` file that can be downloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zarr supports multiple [storage backends](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/storage.html) (DirectoryStore, ZipStore, etc.). If you are looking for a single file object, it sounds like the ZipStore is what you want.

```
import xarray as xr
import zarr

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
store = zarr.storage.ZipStore('./new_zarr.zip')
ds.to_zarr(store)
```

The zip file can be thought of as a single file zarr store and can be downloaded (or moved around as a single store).

---

#### Update 1

If you want to do this all in memory, you could extend `zarr.ZipStore` to allow passing in a BytesIO object:

```py
class MyZipStore(zarr.ZipStore):
    
    def __init__(self, path, compression=zipfile.ZIP_STORED, allowZip64=True, mode='a',
                 dimension_separator=None):

        # store properties
        if isinstance(path, str):  # this is the only change needed to make this work
            path = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.path = path
        self.compression = compression
        self.allowZip64 = allowZip64
        self.mode = mode
        self._dimension_separator = dimension_separator

        # Current understanding is that zipfile module in stdlib is not thread-safe,
        # and so locking is required for both read and write. However, this has not
        # been investigated in detail, perhaps no lock is needed if mode='r'.
        self.mutex = RLock()

        # open zip file
        self.zf = zipfile.ZipFile(path, mode=mode, compression=compression,
                                  allowZip64=allowZip64)
```

Then you can create the create the zip file in memory:

```
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()

store = MyZipStore(zip_buffer)

ds.to_zarr(store)
```

You'll notice that the `zip_buffer` contains a valid zip file:

```
zip_buffer.read(10)
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

(`PK\x03\x04` is the [Zip file magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)))

Comment: thanks for that, my main objective is to write and return a zarr dataset in memory without having to write to disk.

Would I be able to do the following:

`z_file = ds.to_zarr(Zarr.MemoryStore())`

then

`open(shutil.make_archive('file_name', 'zip', z_file), 'rb').read()`

When I try that, it seems that I am not getting bytes returned

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the completely-in-memory use case. This should be supported in Zarr directly, and as it turns out, there is already an open issue for this: https://github.com/zarr-developers/zarr-python/issues/1018